# Is using a global variable as a counter for mongodb documents wrong?

Tags: javascript, express

I am writing an express app and need to keep track of the number of documents in a mongodb database. I know that this can be implemented using a counter collection or external plugins. I want to know if and why using a global variable is wrong.

This is what I am trying to do

```
var counter = noOfDocuments; //assume this is initialized correctly

app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sample', {useNewUrlParser: true});


        var db = mongoose.connection;

        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

        db.once('open', function() {
            console.log("Connection Successful!");

        var password =uuid();
        password = password +(val+1);
        var file = new fileModel({ name: data.name, phoneNo: data.phoneNo , pwd: password ,fileNo : val+1});

        // save model to database
        file.save(function (err, employee1) {
            if (err) {
                mongoose.connection.close();
                return console.error(err);
            }
            mongoose.connection.close();
            val = val+1;
            res.send("Added successfully!")

        });
    });     
});
```

The code is working fine for me currently but I am not sure if it would work when there are multiple simultaneous users due to its asynchronous nature.

Comment: What if you restart your server?

Comment: @Li357 the variable will be initialized correctly initially

Comment: the concern is synchronizing the count with the database reliably. With multiple clients and concurrent deletions and insertions that would be a nightmare and have lots of race conditions

Comment: Global variables have their place, but I wouldn't use such a common name value. Make it less likely to collide with other scripts' variables. `l337counter`

Comment: Where does your script even use `counter`? What do you need the number of documents for?

Comment: @Li357 thats what i feel too. what if there are no deletions and only one way to insert. would it work then? can you provide any links where i can study these race around conditions?

Comment: There is no problem using this approach, unless you have more than one server  or there is any other way to change the count of the documents.